# search engine to a huge mysql database - php

Tags: php, mysql, performance

i have a mysql table with millions of rows

and this it's info

```
id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
dob date NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
age VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
country VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
phone VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
city VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
comment tinytext NOT NULL,
```

what i want to do i a search engine using this query

```
SELECT * FROM dbname
    WHERE name LIKE '%$var%'
      AND ( age = '$age'
      AND phone = '$phone'
      AND country = '$country'
      AND city = '$city')
```

is this query good for performance ? or what should i use ? .. as i said before the table is huge and contain millions of rows

and too many users will use this query per day

thanks in advice,

Comment: Try to run the query on your server and see for yourself if the time it took to complete meets your requirements. If it does not, try to run the EXPLAIN query on it to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

Please learn the technical difference between 'database' and 'table'.  Most of this discussion is about 'tables', not 'databases'.  (A 'database' is a collection of 'tables'; a 'table' contains data in rows and columns.)

Normalize or abbreviate `country`.  The 2-letter codes are good.  Then declare the column

```
    country CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii
```

`age VARCHAR...`??  Use `TINYINT UNSIGNED`, it is much smaller.  Or... Compute it, since you have the `dob`.

`TINYTEXT` has some subtle issues; use the equivalent `VARCHAR(255)`.

Date of birth is considered sensitive information; rethink whether you should be collecting and storing such.

"Millions of rows" does not qualify as 'huge'.  But you will need an index.

`LIKE` with a leading wildcard cannot use an index, so I will ignore the filter dealing with `name`.

You have 4 other columns `AND`d together -- a single index in any or all of them would be very useful.

Since `phone` is likely to be very selective, you could have a simple

```
    INDEX(phone)
```

and that `SELECT` would run very fast.

There is no need to, nor performance advantage in any form of, partitioning or sharding for *this* table and query.